# How to use fftw_plan_many_dft efficiently?

Tags: fft, fftw

I have about 2000 complex fft (size 2048) to calculate and the input/output buffers are allocated continuously. Therefore, I naturally think about using [`fftw_plan_many_dft`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) in hope of accelerating my program.

I am surprised that `fftw_plan_many_dft` is 10 times slower than the normal interface. These are what I have done

- use native complex type and gcc compiler with `O2` flag
- use single precision, i.e. fftw**f**_
- use `fftwf_malloc()` for memory allocation
- use `FFTW_MEASURE` flag (`FFTW_PATIENT` and `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE` are too long)
- use FFTW 3.3.8

Is this issue well-known? Is there anything I should have done differently?